# On 3d ripper DX and other 3d asset tools that can help boost 3d artists learning

Tags: 3d, tools, assets

Aside from 3d ripper DX does anyone know any other 3d asset tools to help 3d artist in learning modelling and/or animations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you can learn modeling from it, but if you mean tools to examine other people's models:
- GLIntercept
 
- MultiEx Commander
- Any gamethat supports mods, and the mods of course
- Milkshape 3d and any site that has models for it.

Comment: I'll look into them.

I'm actually asking to help friends and colleagues as I'm a designer by trade rather than a 3d artist.

I also think it could be useful for the community here as well to know of such tools =)